# Help me choose a particular verb In Present Continous tense

Tags: tense, verbs, present-continuous

I was reading a tenses in the English grammar, and i was doing an exercise, i am confused about choosing a word for following sentence.

```
 I am not going to _________ you again.

Options : (1)meeting (2)meet (3)met
```

so exercise was on Simple continues tense, so which one is appropriate among the first two`(Meeting or Meet)` ??

Thanks..

Comment: For that sentence the correct form would be meet. But I'd argue that that isn't present continuous. "I will not be meeting you again" could be though. I'm sure someone here will come up with an exception but, present continuous should always take -ing.

Comment: Here's a reference for that last comment http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-continuous

Comment: I agree with @PerryW , here is another reference: http://www.englishgrammar.org/difference-present-continuous/, however, they are quite similar and "going" could probably be used in this case.

Comment: 'going to' ***unlike 'looking forward to'*** mostly goes with *infinite*. So, 'meet' and not 'meeting' IMO

Answer (score 2):

The correct word would be "meet" like this:

> I am not going **to meet** you again

Just think of this as the infinitive, "to meet", and the following structure:

person (I) + be conjugated (am) + negative (not) + future (going) + infinitive  (to meet) ....

**So for this question, "meet" is the answer"**

However, you could also say:

> I am not going **to be** *meeting* you again

As this follows the same rule (see the structure above):

I + am + not + going + ***to be*** (this is the infinitive this time) + meeting + you